# iptables port forwarding public network to private network using two interfaces

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding

iptables port forwarding  from incoming connection on public interface to private interface.

I want to do following (in kali linux):

1.) Incoming connection from outside comes to public interface (e.g wlan0, 119.118.117.56:8080)

2.) Forward 119.118.117.56:8080 using private interface (e.g eth0, 172.20.15.5) to 172.20.15.9:443

3.) Get Response from 172.20.15.9:443 to private interface(eth0, 172.20.15.5)

4.) Forward Response from private interface(eth0, 172.20.15.5) to public interface (wlan0, 119.118.117.56:8080) to send response back to incoming connection on public interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `DNAT` rule that will intercept incoming packets and redirect them to the internal IP:

```
iptables -t nat -p tcp -A PREROUTING -j DNAT -d 119.118.117.56 --dport 8080 --to-dest 172.20.15.9:443
```

Unless the internal device 172.20.15.9 uses 172.20.15.5 as default gateway, we need to masquerade packets:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 172.20.15.9 -j MASQUERADE
```

You will also need to allow forwarded (originally incoming) connections from outside:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i wlan0 -p tcp -d 172.20.15.9 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

and allow incoming answers on internal interface:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Also, ip_forwarding must be enabled in the kernel:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

To make this change permanent, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` with the line

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I got following error by running your first command:

iptables v1.8.3 (nf_tables): no command specified

Comment: You're right @MuhammadHaiderAliKhan, I fixed that and also added commands related to ip forwarding

Comment: Thanks,  solved my problem.